# Data transfer over wifi from laptop to Android phone in java

Tags: java

actually I am a CS student and at the end we have to submit a final project. I have developed an idea of making an application, that can be used to transfer data from an android phone to a Windows system over the wifi (something like shareIt). I have studied, java, C, C++, but not really actually built a project with them. The above mentioned is going to be my first, hopefully. What i am really confused in is knowing where to start from. What should i study in java, since i want to build this app with the  java and in addition any other skill that i must master(topics that are to my interest). I have got a year from now to submit my project and I'm willing to spend enough time to master my work. If anyone among you good folks would be kind enough to direct me through. It might seem a lot to reply about, but it might be a big step in making someone good at programming. I really have got this idea and nothing else...Since java is so vast i really don't know where to start from and what to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with Socket:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Android & PC will be the same, you can test your code on your PC first.

Note: On Android, you need to create a separate thread with UI to make the socket work.